# When using GraphDB's Lucene connector, how can I access Lucene directly instead of going through SPARQL?

Tags: lucene, graphdb

I have been playing with GraphDB's [Lucene connector](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/lucene-graphdb-connector.html) as a way to perform full-text search over a large amount of data, via SPARQL queries.  I got the example working.[1](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/lucene-graphdb-connector.html)  Is there another way to read/write Lucene's data, other than going through SPARQL?  For lots of large documents, I am concerned that it may be inefficient to load them all through SPARQL, rather than doing some kind of bulk load directly into Lucene.

Is there a way to access Lucene more directly, instead of going through SPARQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Switch to GraphDB SOLR or Elasticsearch Connectors - both services expose server APIs accessible by other clients. Unfortunately, this feature is available only in GraphDB Enterprise Edition.
- Implement your Lucene server, which works on the same machine running as GraphDB and shares in read-only mode the Lucene index managed by GraphDB.

Comment: how do you switch to the GraphDB SOLR connector? In my workbench at Setup/Connectors, I only see the Lucene connector and the option of "New Lucene connector" .

Comment: SOLR and ElasticSearch Connectors are available only in GraphDB EE, but not in GraphDB SE or Free